# Is it safe to use "sub" claim in keycloak token for user id in internal DB

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt, keycloak, openid-connect

I'm working on an application that may support social logins in future (in addition to our own keycloak username/email signup).

I'm trying to determine if it's safe to use the "sub" claim that comes in keycloak ID token, as a primary key (the "_id" field) for users in our internal mongo db. I'd ideally like to use an id from the token, as it may save me needing to make an extra User lookup in some cases in our api.

I see Microsoft azure docs show their auth token has both "sub" and "oid", where the "oid" is recommended to be used for user lookup internally as it's globally unique. [See this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens#payload-claims).

> This ID uniquely identifies the user across applications - two different applications signing in the same user will receive the same value in the oid claim. The Microsoft Graph will return this ID as the id property for a given user account.

So is there an equivalent of the "oid" claim in keycloak, do I need to add a custom claim to achieve the equivalent, or am I ok just to use the "sub" claim instead?

Comment: [Based on what I understood from this doc](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#javascript-adapter-reference) if you are using its javascript adaptor you can safely use `subject` since it is an UUID I doubt you will face any duplication. But in general I advise to let MongoDB generates its own ID  and you can just add a new indexed field to your collection.

Comment: **BTW I also tested and realized that sub in the JWT token is the User ID.** Also `keycloak.subject` holds the same value as `keycloak?.tokenParsed?.sub`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking [JSON Web Token (JWT)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519) documentation, namely at *"sub" (Subject) Claim* section:

**4.1.2.  "sub" (Subject) Claim**

> The "sub" (subject) claim identifies the principal that is the      subject of the JWT. (...). **The subject value MUST either be scoped to be locally unique in the context of the issuer or be globally unique**.  The processing of this claim is **generally application specific**.
> (...). Use of this claim is **OPTIONAL**.

From my interpretation of this text alone, it is not guaranteed that the `sub` claim for a given user will be the same among different applications (*i.e.,* clients). Moreover, that claim is optional.

So to answer your question precisely we need to look at
the context of [OpenID connect](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#StandardClaims):

> The primary extension that OpenID Connect makes to OAuth 2.0 to enable End-Users to be Authenticated **is the ID Token** data structure.
>
> **sub** :  **REQUIRED**. Subject Identifier. A locally unique and never reassigned identifier within the Issuer for the End-User, which is intended to be consumed by the Client (...).

Okey, from this text and the fact that to get the `ID Token` you must pass to the request the `openid` scope, you can be sure that the `sub` claim will be presented in the `ID Token`.

Regarding the question whether the `sub` will be the same for all Clients, this is also address in the same document under the [Subject Identifier Types](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#SubjectIDTypes) section:

> **Subject Identifier Types**
>
> A Subject Identifier is a locally unique and never reassigned
> identifier within the Issuer for the End-User, which is intended to be consumed by the Client.

> **Two Subject Identifier types are defined by this specification**:
>
> **public** - This provides the **same sub (subject) value to all Clients**. It is the default if the provider has no subject_types_supported element in its discovery document.

> **pairwise** - This provides a different sub
> value to each Client, so as not to enable Clients to correlate the
> End-User's activities without permission.

> The OpenID Provider's
> Discovery document SHOULD list its supported Subject Identifier types
> in the subject_types_supported element. If there is more than one type
> listed in the array, the Client MAY elect to provide its preferred
> identifier type using the subject_type parameter during Registration.

[Since a while](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-3422) now, keycloak support both `public` and `pairwise` subject identifier types. If not explicitly specified
the `public` one is used by default.

So to conclude:

> or am I ok just to use the "sub" claim instead?

Yes, as long as you take into account the subject identifier type being used.

Answer (score 2):

The subject value MUST either be scoped to be [locally unique in the context of the issuer](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#section-4.1.2) or be globally unique.

So a combination of the "sub" (Subject) Claim and the "iss" (Issuer) Claim is always globally unique.