# How can I set Keycloak user id as static?

Tags: keycloak

I am using Keycloak for authentication.

I used the user id in the access token as a user identity and stored it in some tables when users did some actions. I have some counters relying on *user-id*.

But recently, I found that the Keycloak user id is dynamic and it is changed after some time(I am not sure how long a *user-id* is kept) that making my counters counted improperly.

So I wonder is there a way that we set the user id static? And how can I get the user email from the user-id that had been changed in the past?

I am really appreciated your help and suggestions. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100 % sure about:

> But recently, I found that the Keycloak user id is dynamic and it is
> changed after some time( I am not sure how long a user-id is kept)
> that making my counters counted improperly.

You can use the claim `sub` in combination with a *public* *subject identifier types*. Have a look a [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72590383/1366871) for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: it was my mistake. I used two accounts with the same username and different email IDs. When I ran the query with username filter, it returned 2 user id. That's why I think the user id generated by Keycloak is dynamic.

Confirm again: the user-id is fixed.